# No suitable constructor found for XSSF Workbook

Tags: java, excel

I have added all the jar files poi-ooxml,poi,domj4,xml beans but still its not supporting to read the xlsx file.i have imported all the things need to work with XSSf in java program.Dont know why its not supporting XSSf constructor.i have created xssf workbook for file and tried with opcpackage and inputsream but none of the constructorwas not worked.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;
import org.postgresql.largeobject.LargeObject;
import org.postgresql.largeobject.LargeObjectManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;


import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
```

the above headers i have imported and i tried like

```
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(relative);
       XSSFWorkbook wb11 = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
```

Its showing error like no suitable constructor found.

Comment: Maybe you are using an older version? Please list your jar file versions.

Comment: poi-ooxml-3.9 jar,dom4j1.5.jar,xmlbeans.2.3.0 jar,poi 3.9 jar,poi-ooxm-jar,poi-ooxml-3,7 sources jar,poi-ooxml schemas.jar

Comment: Its enough to include the four necessary jars??

Comment: three different poi-ooxml jar files? Mixing 3.9 and 3.7. Why is that?

Comment: I am new to java.Could you guide me?Do i have to add all the above on same version?? @Thilo

Comment: Get the latest stable POI release and use the jar files included there: http://poi.apache.org/download.html#POI-3.11

Comment: Okay.I will check it out and then let you know@Thilo

Comment: Thank you.I have remove the other jar files.It was worked thank you!!!!@Thilo